# scipy optimize fmin syntax

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

```
numseq = ['0012000', '0112000', '0212000', '0312000', '1012000', '1112000',                                                                                   '1212000', '1312000', '2012000', '2112000', '2212000', '2312000', '3012000', '3112000',          '3212000', '3312000', '0002000', '0022000', '0032000', '1002000', '1022000', '1032000',     '2002000', '2022000', '2032000', '3002000', '3022000', '3032000', '0010000', '0011000', '0013000', '1010000', '1011000', '1013000', '2010000', '2011000', '2013000', '3010000', '3011000', '3013000', '0012100', '0012200', '0012300', '1012100', '1012200', '1012300', '2012100', '2012200', '2012300', '3012100']
prob = [-0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.78361598908750163, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.66474525640568083, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212, -0.49518440694747212]
```

`numseq` and `prob` are lists of length 50 each. They are the experimental data that is collected. `numseq` corresponds to the X axis values, and `prob` corresponds to the Y axis values.

The function that I want to minimise is:

```
def residue(allparams, xdata, ydata):
    chi2 = 0.0
    for i in range(0,len(xdata)):
        x = xdata[i]
        y = 0
        for j in range(len(x)):
            y = y-allparams[int(x[j])][j]
            chi2 = chi2 + (ydata[i]-y)**2
return chi2
```

So:

- `allparams` is a 4×7 matrix, which contains all the parameters to be optimized.
- `xdata` is the X-axis values, i.e `numseq`
- `ydata` is just a list of numbers i.e `prob`

`chi2` is the squared difference between the experimental and model values. This is what has to be minimised.

The initial guess for the parameters is given by:

```
x0 = [[-0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6], [-0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6], [-0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6], [-0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6]]
```

Now how do I call `fmin` on this function? I tried

```
fmin(residue, x0, args=(numseq, prob))
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#362>", line 1, in <module>
    fmin(residue, x0, args=(numseq, prob))
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 258, in fmin
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 177, in function_wrapper
    return function(x, *args)
  File "<pyshell#361>", line 7, in residue
    y = y-allparams[int(x[j])][j]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

why is this so? Is it because `fmin` can't accept 2D arrays as initial guesses? Then do i have to change my entire code to work on a 1D array of parameters?

Even if you can't explain this problem, could you at least tell me how exactly the `fmin` module works? i.e the syntax of how to implement `fmin` for the optimization of an N-dimensional array? Could you explain what `args()` is? I'm new to optimisation and I have no idea on how to implement it :(

Comment: The `residue` function, as first posted, appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The "fmin" routine can accept 2d arrays as an initial guess. But the first thing it does is flatten this array [(4,7) --> (28)]. So what happens is that your residue function takes a (4,7) array as an input and the "fmin" routine gives it a flattened "x0" of length 28. That's why you see the error:
`y = y-allparams[int(x[j])][j]`
`IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`
[See the source code here.](http://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L264)

So it appears that you will have to change your residue function to accept a vector instead of an array. This doesn't seem too bad however. I tried the following which seemed to work (Note: Please double check!)

```python
def residue_alternative(allparams, inshape, xdata, ydata):
    m, n = inshape
    chi2 = 0.0
    for i in range(0,len(xdata)):
        x = xdata[i]
        y = 0
        for j in range(len(x)):
            idx = int(x[j]) * n +  j #Double check this to 
            y = y-allparams[idx]     #make sure it does what you want
            chi2 = chi2 + (ydata[i]-y)**2
    return chi2
```

I called it using:

```python
x0 = -0.6 * np.ones((4,7), dtype=np.double)
[xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag] = \
    fmin(residue_alternative, x0, args=(x0.shape, numseq, prob),
       maxiter = 100000,
       maxfun  = 100000,
       full_output=True,
       disp=True)
```

And received the following results:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 7.750523
         Iterations: 21570
         Function evaluations: 26076

>>>xopt
array([ 0.57669042, -0.21965861,  0.2635061 , -0.08284016, -0.0779489 ,
   -0.10358114,  0.14041582,  0.72469391, -0.43190214,  0.31269757,
   -0.0338726 , -0.14919739, -2.58314651,  2.74251214,  0.57695759,
   -0.49574628,  0.1490926 ,  0.04912353,  0.02420988,  1.17924051,
   -7.2147027 ,  0.57860843, -0.28386938,  0.2431877 , -0.22674694,
   -0.58308225, -6.05706775, -2.06350063])
```

Which you can reshape to a 4x7 array. Give this a try and let me know if it works/helps.